# How to remove nested object form apollo cache?

Tags: caching, apollo-client

[Official doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/garbage-collection/#cacheevict) says remove cache data using `cache.evict()`, but there are no explanation about nested object. For example, let's think abount `ROOT_QUERY` like below.

```
ROOT_QUERY: {
  analysis: {
    receipts: { 
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I can remove `analysis` field by using `cache.evict()`.

```js
cache.evict({ id: 'ROOT_QUERY', fieldName: 'analysis' });
```

**But, how can I remove `receipts` field?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cache.modify`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#using-cachemodify) for nested object.

```js
cache.modify({
  id: 'ROOT_QUERY',
  fields: {
    analysis(existing) {
      return {
        ...existing,
        receipts: undefined
      };
    }
  }
});
```